# Xpath rules - contains() not returning what I'd like

Tags: xpath, contains, xpath-2.0

So far I have the following Xpath set to pull the word 'gallery' from an href but it returns the entire url instead of just the word gallery. Could you help explain what I'm doing wrong please? Thanks you, it's much appreciated!

```
$x("//link[@rel='canonical' and contains(@href,'gallery')]")
```

Comment: Do you want it to return the word gallery just once if any such link exists, or once for each link for which the predicate yields true? (Either way, it's a strange requirement.)

Comment: Anything in square brackets influences whether or not something is selected, but it doesn't influence what is returned for things that are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your current XPath expression,

```
$x("//link[@rel='canonical' and contains(@href,'gallery')]")
```

returns a sequence of `<link>` elements. Depending on the way you evaluate them, you might be getting their text content.

If you just want the word `'gallery'`, in XPath 2.0 you can say

```
$x("//link[@rel='canonical' and contains(@href,'gallery')]/'gallery'")
```

which will return a sequence of strings, one `'gallery'` for each `<link>` element that fulfills the predicate.

Or you could say

```
$x("if (exists(//link[@rel='canonical' and contains(@href,'gallery')]))
       then 'gallery' else null")
```

which will return either `'gallery'` (once), or null.